# How to make Excel script/macro which searches for a cell with specific data?

Tags: microsoft-excel

There is need

```
1.to get current active cell (selected one),
2. get data it holds (date DD.MM.YY), 
3. search for the same date in other book (or same), 
4. copy found cell on the right to (Sheet1 right next to date on the right).
```

Any examples how to do this? [image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the VLOOKUP function to search for a matching index from a column.

```
VLOOKUP(lookup_value,table_array,col_index_num,range_lookup)
```